# Помогите решить ошибку с SpeechRecohnitionEngine

Tags: c#

При коде

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-ru");
SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ci);
```

Выдает ошибку:
System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Я так понял это из-за "ru-ru", но что делать подскажите.. Почему оно так, и как это решить?

Comment: `ru-RU` же https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Globalization_CultureInfo__ctor_System_String_

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-5.0#GetAll